# Firebase cloud messages fail to send android after switching firebase projects

Tags: android, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-cloud-messaging, messaging

I am developing an ionic angular app, the app has two firebase projects one for dev environment and another for live, I have set up cloud messaging on both.
I had successfully set up FCM on my dev project and it was working on both iOS and android, however im now trying to switch over to the live project and firebase messages are no longer received by android devices (everything works fine on ios)

I have tried updating the google-services.json file to match the new project however this doesn't fix it, no error messages appear but messages just dont send. Configuration for android app in firebase matches in both projects.